# JSF ui:insertChildren fine when the component is in the same project, fails when in it is in a taglib

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have a fairly simple JSF component:

```
<composite:interface>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <mytaglib:jquery-ui/>
    <h:outputScript target="head" library="com.mytaglib.mytaglib" name="dockwidget/dockwidget.js"/>
    <f:subview>
    <div id="${component.clientId}_div">
        <composite:insertChildren/>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout("$(document.getElementById('${component.clientId}_div')).dockWidget();", 50);
    });
    </script>       
    </f:subview>
```

I've included that in a taglib jar (maven project linked in Eclipse) with the required entry in the mytaglib.taglib.xml. When I use it this way then the insertChildren does not seem to pick up the children. Everything else renders fine - including a test "Hello World" if I insert it into the div in the control.

If I take the xhtml file and place it under resources/localcontrols and refer to that copy in my page.xhtml it works and the child components are included.

Is this normal?

Thanks
 - Richard

(As an aside - the setTimeout because my layout javascript was running too early - before the child components had been fully rendered. I wonder if JQuery has a way of solving this properly.)

Comment: No, this is not normal. What JSF impl/version? By the way, the `<f:subview>` is utterly wrongly used there. Remove it. Do not ever use it in Facelets. It's only useful in JSPs.

Comment: I'm using JBoss 7 with shipped JSF. I'm trialling IceFaces.  

I needed a Naming Parent, so used Subview for that? Is there another way to get a naming parent or unique name?

Comment: A composite component is already a naming container.

Comment: I tried ${component.clientId} and found when I repeated my component they all got the same Id. I've noticed other code using ${cc.clientId} so can try that. I'm out of the office until Tuesday now, so will be then. I thought I'd tried cc.clientId. Will try again, maybe something else was wrong.